# VS2022: Is there a faster way to toggle "Enable Native Code Debugging" setting?

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, unmanaged, visual-studio-2022, managed

I work on a solution with both managed (C#) and native (C++) code.  The managed code calls into the C++.   I typically have native code debugging disabled because it makes the whole experience slower but I have many times where I need to enable it.

Unfortunately the process is cumbersome:

1. Right click on project.
2. Choose "Properties".
3. Choose "Debug" category.
4. Click "Open Launch Profiles UI".
5. Scroll down.
6. Click the "Native Code Debugging" checkbox.

I wanted to make this faster.  I was hoping there might be some command for it that I could bind a key to.  I tried going into *Tools >> Customize* and searching for a command that had "Native" or "Managed" in it.  I didn't find anything that was like what I want.

Does anyone know a faster way to toggle this setting?

Comment: No, there is no dedicated command for it.  You could write a tiny little program that modifies the project's .csproj.user file.

Comment: Ah is that where it's stored?  Maybe I'll use this as my excuse to try to write my very first VS Extension

Answer (score 2):

Answering my own question here.  I am not sure if this has been in Visual Studio for a while or if they recently added it but I had not noticed it before.  Turns out a much faster way is to go to the Debug Menu and choose the very last item.

"*(Your Project Name]* Properties"

That takes you right there.  Still no hotkey but much better than the multi-step way I've been doing.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `launchSettings.json` file and it would look something like this:

```json
{
  "profiles": {
    "NameOfYourCSharpProject": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "nativeDebugging": true
    }
  }
}
```

I verified you can do this even if your project is .Net Framework; though you'll have to first you want to convert your `.csproj` over to SDK style if it isn't already.  It is to be put in the `Properties` directory of your C# project.

So if you find yourself toggling between wanting Native Code Debugging on/off I suppose you could make two executable projects one with this setting in the `launchsSettings.json` file and the other without.  And toggle between start-up projects.  Or something like that.

Comment: Is there a way to configure that also for legacy projects (not SDK style ones)? Thank you.

Comment: I don't think so.  But MS release Upgrade-Assistant and it converts projects rather easily.  And being SDK style is very important to do dual-targeting and more.